# Mathematica File Organization

Tags: packages, interoperability, palettes, stylesheet, document-creation

Last year I asked how to [integrate notebooks to the documentation center](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6574710/788553) in stackoverflow. Back then I was only interested in seeing those notebook and being able to search for them. Unfortunately, it has been painful to write the documentation because of the lack of a good organized stylesheet (Still working on a simple one that does the job). In any case, I would like to revisit part of this question by looking at complete tree of the file organization of a package. In the answers I posted I showed mainly the part for the documentation.

[image: example]

In the picture above I show the folder `SOPackage` which is supposed to be located either in `$UserBaseDirectory` or `$BaseDirectory`. Now that I know a little bit more of stylesheets, palettes and mathlink programs I would like to be able to incorporate them to applications. The question is, can anyone show a a complete tree of an application located in either `$UserBaseDirectory` or `$BaseDirectory` with the folders necessary to make everything work? (By everything I mean, documentation, mathlink/NETlink/LibraryLink programs, stylesheets, palettes and any other thing that you can think of).

A place to start is at:

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframSystemFileOrganization.html

But it doesn't seem to have everything. The reason I found out about how to create the structure in the picture above was because of a [link](http://www.dbaileyconsultancy.co.uk/m_documentation/m_documentation.html) acl showed in one of his [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6516798/788553).

To clarify again, the question at hand is: Can we show the complete structure of an application in `$UserBaseDirectory` that contains the directories where we put:

1. Documentation
2. Source Code for Mathlink/NETLink/LibraryLink (any other link)
3. Stylesheets
4. Palettes

If you can think of anything else that would make the application more complete please add it.

At some point I wanted to just ask if it was possible to put stylesheets in an application instead of

```
$UserBaseDirectory <> "/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/";
```

but instead I decided to make a question that can bring all of us the complete file organization for a complete application in *Mathematica*.

Comment: Regardless of the quality of the answers you are going to get, I would frankly suggest you to really consider buying Workbench. After all the time, money and energy you have already invested in Mathematica, the added $145 investment in Workbench might be negligible compared to the "pain" and aggravation you describe in order to obtain state of the art package documentation and all the other features you can easily get with Workbench.

Comment: @magma, I'm sorry but I rather not. I tried it at some point but after finding out that you still do things using the simple Mathematica installation I realized that it was just another fancy front end. I rather know what Workbench is doing and organize things the way I see fit (following the rules of Mathematica of course).

Comment: The link above for Mathematica File Organization no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

Why not `myApplication/FrontEnd/Palettes` and `myApplication/FrontEnd/StyleSheets` (where `myApplication` is the name of the aplication)? Many applications in my `$UserBaseDirectory <> "Applications"` directory use that.

Comment: That is where I currently have them but I'm not sure yet how to access those stylesheets from there. As I mentioned in the question if you put them in `$UserBaseDirectory <> "/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/"` then if you restart *Mathematica* or you run the command: ``MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`ResetMenusPacket[{Automatic, Automatic}]]`` then you will see those stylesheets in the menu.

Comment: @jmlopez, you don't need to do anything to access the stylesheets from there. That's by default in the stylesheet lookup path

Comment: @Rojo, Are they not supposed to be on the stylesheet menu?

Comment: Ok, got it, I was making a very stupid mistake, I named it `Stylesheets` instead of `StyleSheets`. Well, that takes care of where to place the styleSheets. Not sure yet how to make them appear in the menu. Is there some way of making them appear as part the application providing them?

Comment: I think they should be in the menu after a restart. Alternatively you can try to use `ResetMenusPacket` as you have mentioned. Doesn't that work for you? Same thing goes for any palette you want to supply: just put it in `"myapp/FrontEnd/Palettes"` and they should appear after a restart or `ResetMenusPacket`.

Comment: @AlbertRetey, This is a directory I have: `/Users/jmlopez/Library/Mathematica/Applications/ApplicationMaker/FrontEnd/StyleSheets`, the documentation is working for `ApplicationMaker` but the stylesheets I have in `StyleSheets` do not appear anywhere on the menu. The only ones that show up are the ones in: `/Users/jmlopez/Library/Mathematica/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets`

Comment: I have only a windows and linux box available right now, but it would work for both of them as I mentioned. I would be surprised if the Mac version would behave different. Maybe I can later check on a Mac, too. Have you checked the settings of `$UserBaseDirectory` and `Options[$FrontEnd, "StyleSheetPath"]`? The latter should show something like `FrontEnd`FileName[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", _, "FrontEnd", 
  "StyleSheets"}]`

Comment: ... which should indicate what your package directory structure must match so that the stylesheets will be found...(this and the above of course go @jmlopez)

Comment: tried it on a mac now as well. Works as advertised. I would guess that you either have messed up your settings or have a weired typo in one of the directory names. Can you exclude that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3979/discussion-between-jmlopez-and-albert-retey)